# Python - SQLAlchemy - MySQL - multiple instances work on same data

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I have a table in a database, mapped with SQLAlchemy ORM module (I have a "scoped_session" Variable)
I want multiple instances of my program (not just threads, also from several servers) to be able to work on the same table and NOT work on the same data.
so i have coded a manual "row-lock" mechanism to make sure each row is handled in this method i use "Full Lock" on the table while i "row-lock" it:

```
def instance:
        s = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        engine.execute("LOCK TABLES my_data WRITE")
        rows = s.query(Row_model).filter(Row_model.condition == 1).filter(Row_model.is_locked == 0).limit(10)
        for row in rows:
            row.is_locked = 1
            row.lock_time = datetime.now()
        s.commit()
        engine.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
        for row in row:
            manipulate_data(row)
            row.is_locked = 0
        s.commit()

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=instance)
    t.start()
```

The problem is that while running some instances, several threads are collapsing and produce this error (each):

> sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked
>   autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush
>   is occurring prematurely) (DatabaseError) 1205 (HY000): Lock wait
>   timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction 'UPDATE my_daya SET
>   row_var = 1}

Where is the catch? what makes my DB table to not UNLOCK successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Locks are evil. Avoid them. Things go very bad when errors occur. Especially when you mix sessions with raw SQL statements, like you do.

The beauty of the scoped session is that it wraps a database transaction. This transaction makes the modifications to the database atomic, and also takes care of cleaning up when things go wrong.

Use scoped sessions as follows:

```
with scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine) as s:
    <ORM actions using s>
```

It may be some work to rewrite your code so that it becomes properly transactional, but it will be worth it! Sqlalchemy has tricks to help you with that.